# How to automatically press Ctrl+h with Autohotkey when I run Adobe Reader?

Tags: autohotkey

I want Adobe Reader to start in reader mode (by default it can be done by Ctrl+h) so I would like to make ahk script that press Ctrl+h if Adobe Reader starts, but I don't know how..

Comment: Which Adobe Reader version are you using? Maybe the optione `Display in read mode by default` or the RegKey mentioned [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2011/11/turning-off-read-mode-while-viewing-pdfs-in-your-browser/) already does what you want. I can't check it since I don't know your version.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I'm using adobe reader XI (11.0.5) and what you posted is solution only for the appearence in web browser and not for the program itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write your own relatively simple loop or adapt a pre-made script such as [this one](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/84397-winwait-framework-do-something-to-a-window-when-it-appears/) to check for the correct window title, class and/or executable.

If you write your own you can either do a polling loop or use `WinWaitActive` to wait for the right window to appear, then send the keys, for example:

```
loop
{
    currentID := WinExist("A")
    WinWaitNotActive, ahk_id currentID
    IfWinActive, ahk_exe Acrobat.exe
        Send ^h  ; Send Ctrl+H
}
```

This is an oversimplified example as a starting point.  It does not account for the same window becoming inactive and then active again, in which case you wouldn't need to re-initialize Adobe Reader.

If you adapt the code at the link it is easy enough to set up and you can configure it with Option B or C to only initialize Adobe Reader every time it becomes active or once each time a new window appears.  Make sure to use tabs in the setup section of this code and not spaces (depends on your editor).